# Java printf not printing

Tags: java, printing, console

I'm trying to make a cross platform console progress indicator in Java. Therefore I use the System.out.printf method to print out a percentage:

```
System.out.printf("\t%2.2f%%\b\b\b\b\b\b", percentage);
```

and I place this in a for loop. The problem I encounter is that it's not printing anything until the whole for loop is done. This is a program example to show the problem:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i =0; i<5000; i++){
            System.out.printf("\b\b\b\b\b\b%2.2f%%", ((float) i/5000f)*100f);
            System.out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem has something to do with compiler optimisation, but I'm not shure. The strange thing is that `System.out.println` does print when the for loop is running.

Edit: I forgot to add it to the problem. But I had allready tried to flush the buffer. This makes no difference. Adding `%n` to the end of my printf line works but it starts a newline, I really need it to reuse the current line.

All opposed solutions work. But they only work in real consoles. Not the netbeans or eclipse console.

Comment: Your code works for me, but is a bit fast, so I included a `try {
             Thread.sleep (10);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the output stream is line buffered. If you add a "%n" at the end of your format string you also generate a line break and the line will be flushed (i.e. printed). Alternatively call `System.out.flush()` to manually flush the output stream and force buffered contents to be printed.

Answer (score 2):

And once more the problem is with flushing the stream. Add this line after your `printf`:

```
System.out.flush();
```

`System.out.println` is flushing (much like C++'s `<< endl`). However, `printf` is not flushing and is using buffer.

Comment: Flush is method so you need brackets for sure.

Comment: I had added brackets in my original code, I see they were not copied. I fixed it in the starting post. The problem is still not solved.

Comment: and what is the goal to replace the old characters with the new ones so you get something similar to counter?

Comment: I want to make a progress indicator. When I have like 5000 steps to calculate I don't want to print out 5000 lines but only one line showing the percentage of how much has been processed allready.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It turns out it was the console from netbeans that didn't respond as a normal console.

Comment: You should have tried the Eclipse console. I needed to resort to command line in order to test your code.

Answer (score 1):

Add a call to `flush()`:

```
    for(int i =0; i<5000; i++){
        System.out.printf("\b\b\b\b\b\b%2.2f%%", ((float) i/5000f)*100f);
        System.out.flush();
    }
```

Without the `flush()`, the output gets accumulated in a buffer that only gets flushed once in a while (whenever it's full, or whenever a newline is printed).

> The strange thing is that `System.out.println` does print when the for loop is running.

The reason for that is that the stream is line-buffered. This means that every newline triggers an implicit flush. The difference between your code and `println()` is that the latter prints out a newline every time it's called.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Console](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) instead:

```
for(int i =0; i<5000; i++){
    System.console().format("\b\b\b\b\b\b%2.2f%%", ((float) i/5000f)*100f);
    System.console().flush();
}
```